# Replacing line in file that start with a string if exist and add if not

Tags: python-2.7

I created code to check  if line start with string exist or not and if exist update and if not add it.
it works but i think it may there another way instead of opening the file and close it three times !!

My text is (try)

```
LINE1, 1111111
LINE2, 2222222
LINE4, 4444444 
LINE3, 4444444
```

and the code i tried:

```py
linename = 'LINE3'  # Variable
num = 3333333  # Variable

f = open('try', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open('try', "w")

for line in lines:
    if not line.startswith(str(linename)):
        f.write(line)

f.close()

f = open('try', 'a+')
for line in f:
    if line.startswith(str(linename)):
        break
else:
    f.write("{0}, {1} \n" .format(linename, num))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
linename = 'LINE3'
num = 3333333

with open('try', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

found = False
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith(linename):
        lines[i] = "{0}, {1}".format(linename, num)
        found = True
        break

if not found:
    lines.append("{0}, {1}".format(linename, num)

with open('try', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

The next logical step would be to make a function out of it:

```
def store_in_file(filename, linename, num):
    # ... the above ...


store_in_file('try', 'LINE3', 3333333)
```

Comment: thanks for your support in this, but it still not exactly what i need , 
i think as you said i must rewrite the file.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: I think you can find that out by reading the documentation. ;)